# Extruder 2 is not printing

Tags: extruder

For my printer (3DGence Double255) there is no ready to use Cura profile available. So I started to edit one.

Until now I left the start code for the two extruders empty. But, the machine is printing everything with extruder 1.

Now I am wondering if the printer needs a special extruder change command in the start code.

And what would be the end code?